# What is causing this wall to only shows on the render and render preview?

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

When I am at the material preview it all looks great and ready, but when I go to render preview or complete a render this wall goes straight through the midle of the scene, I have checked many times it is not a plane or something I left or set there, it only shows on preview as the image below shows.

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: in the outliner look for any object that has the camera icon highlighted but the eye icon replaced with a 'closed' (single small curve) "eye".  Also, which wall is the weird one?

Comment: Checked they are all set to visible ( open ) 
I added 2 more pictures for better visual 
It{s the one that seems to have no texture. ( left one on last picture )

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried to select that mesh while in render preview?

Comment: That is like main issue when I try to select it there is nothing there
I went through every single mesh by taking of the visible option and it was still there 
................................. Oh found what it was, there was an issue with the material on one of the painting frames, had the height connected to height and not normal on the shading scrren causing well this issue. 
All fix 
Thanks guys !!